# How to set the environmental variable for my scripts same as the users shell?

Tags: shell-script

I want to know how to set the environmental variable for my scripts that I have written such that they are the same as the user. This way I can save time in giving an absolute path of the command.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to set cron job for another user as a root .

Comment: @KALAISELVAN I updated my answer to accommodate your updated question.

Comment: Classic [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), voting to close...

Answer (score 2):

The shell script will automatically be the environment variable of the user executing the script.

You might consider more importantly how to specify extra variables for your scripts.  To add to the default path of the user running the script you would add a line such as:

```
PATH="$PATH:/newAddedPath"
```

That will add to the path the area you want included.

---

**Updated answer to updated question:**

You can run your cron as root with:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

You can run your cron as any other user by with:

```
$ sudo crontab -u [userid] -e
```

Keep in mind that root doesn't have the same default path as normal users.  You can check to see what path you have as root with:

```
$ sudo su -
# echo $PATH
# exit
```

So to ensure you have your path variable the way you need it add the path statement at the top of this answer to the beginning of your script.